# Simple MDX Filter Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, cube

Can anyone explain why this one fails :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[T]
as
    Filter(
                [Customer].[Customer Name].Children,
                [Measures].[Sales] > 65042.79
        )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[T] on 0
FROM [SalesCube]
```

while this one is fine?

```
SELECT 
    Filter(
            [Customer].[Customer Name].Children,
            [Measures].[Sales] > 65042.79
        ) on 0
FROM [SalesCube]
```

The first one gives an errror

*"The function expects a string or numeric expression for the argument. A tuplet set expression was used."*

They look exactly the same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised that it should have been

```
WITH SET [T]
as
    Filter(
                [Customer].[Customer Name].Children,
                [Measures].[Sales] > 65042.79
        )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[T] on 0
FROM [SalesCube]
```

Comment: Good job! Tick you answer as accepted answer to close the question.